# Revising Python function

Tags: python, function, dbase

So I have the code you can see down below. I am trying to write a function to pull the info from specific fields in different dbase files. I wrote a function called get field as you see below, but its not saving me much, if any space or coding. I tried the following:

```
def get_field(file_number, field_info):
    info = file(file_number).records[0][field_info]
    return info
```

My plan was to be able to just call the function and pass a 0, 1, and 13 in for the file, then the field im looking for but i get an error saying the file doesnt exist. Anyone better at this than me that can push me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
from dbfread import DBF
from mailmerge import MailMerge
import os

path = 'C:/Users/kevin/Documents/ccc-export'
if os.path.isfile('C:/Users/kevin/Documents/ccc-export/file0'):
    pass
else:
    path = 'C:/Users/kevin/Documents/ccc-export'
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, 'file' + str(i)))
        i = i + 1

file1 = DBF('C:/Users/kevin/Documents/ccc-export/file0', load=True, ignore_missing_memofile=True)
file2 = DBF('C:/Users/kevin/Documents/ccc-export/file1', load=True, ignore_missing_memofile=True)
file3 = DBF('C:/Users/kevin/Documents/ccc-export/file13', load=True, ignore_missing_memofile=True)


def get_field(file_number, field_info):
    info = file_number.records[0][field_info]
    return info


# from file 1
claim_num = get_field(file1, 'CLM_NO')
adjust_name = file1.records[0]['CLM_CT_FN'], file1.records[0]['CLM_CT_LN']
adjuster_name = ' '.join(adjust_name)
adjuster_number = file1.records[0]['CLM_PH1']
insur_name = file1.records[0]['INSD_FN'], file1.records[0]['INSD_LN']
insured_name = ' '.join(insur_name)
own_name = file1.records[0]['OWNR_FN'], file1.records[0]['OWNR_LN']
owner_name = ' '.join(own_name)
owner_phone = 'Need to get from diff file, none listed for this file'
loss_date = file1.records[0]['LOSS_DATE']

loss_date_str = loss_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

# from file 2
apprais_name = file2.records[0]['EST_CT_FN'], file2.records[0]['EST_CT_LN']
appraiser_name = ' '.join(apprais_name)
loss_zip = file2.records[0]['INSP_ZIP']
loss_state = file2.records[0]['INSP_ST']
loss_type = file2.records[0]['INSP_DESC']

# from file 3

vehicle_vin = file3.records[0]['V_VIN']
vehicle_year = file3.records[0]['V_MODEL_YR']
vehicle_make = file3.records[0]['V_MAKECODE']
vehicle_model = file3.records[0]['V_MODEL']
vehicle_engine = file3.records[0]['V_ENGINE']
vehicle_mileage = file3.records[0]['V_MILEAGE']
```

Comment: Let's do some basic debugging here before we involve Stack Overflow. Which part of your code results in "the file doesnt exist"? Is that the exact error message (hint: no). Was there an exception? Which line of code triggered the exception? What was the filename you passed to the function that triggered the exception? Is it a valid filename?

Comment: Please include the traceback of the error, we cannot help you if we don't even know what is really wrong.